# Generating a Risk ID through Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a table of Risks and Issues with an RiskIssue_ID column.

Risk IDs should be like "R0001","R0002" etc

Issue IDs should be like "I0001","I0002" etc

Entries done via form. User specifies whether it's a Risk or Issue, that he wants to save.
I can use that to create a string starting with 'R' or 'I'. But I also need to find the last used number for 'R' or 'I', so that I can set a new ID for the new entry.

E.g. If user is saving a risk and 15 risks are already saved, Last Risk ID in the Table is 'R0015'. I need the new risk to be saved as 'R0016'

Thank you in advance for all your illuminated assistance.

Comment: You can use SQL, look at the MAX function, not sure this will work with the R etc, but you could say "select top 1 RiskID from tbl_Risks order by RiskID desc" which may work

Comment: Hey Nathan
Worked like magic. Thanks a lot

Comment: No probs, i'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL, look at the MAX function, not sure this will work with the R etc, but you could say `"select top 1 RiskID from tbl_Risks order by RiskID desc"` which may work